# Can phpinfo show different values than the actuals (on a shared hosting)?

Tags: php, cpanel, php-ini

I am having an argument with a hosting company service agent and I am trying to figure out if they don't know what they are talking about or I am wrong here...

I have set on my php.ini
`session.gc_maxlifetime to 21600`

phpinfo() shows 21600 as local and master value

The representative insists that cpanel (?) is limiting that to the default 1440.

Can my phpinfo show 21600 while in fact the limit is 1440 wihout being shown anywhere to me?

Thanks!

Comment: There are scenarios where the garbage collection is handled via a backend process that might be using a different php.ini in the CLI. I wouldn't necessarily trust support on a shared hosting service; my experiences with them has been "they either lie or have no idea".

Comment: I believe that's the default configuration for cPanel. Not the server itself. The application can override the settings as needed for its own purposes.

Comment: That is exactly what I am saying. That the defaulf of php (not cpanel) is 1440 but I am overriding it with the php.ini. But they are arguing that eventhough I set it to 21600 and it shows like that on phpinfo, they have set it to be max 1440 somehow... Is this possible?

Comment: It's possible, yes. If you want to be tweaking stuff like this, get off shared hosting, and off cPanel.